# org.openntf.domino api Stackoverflow error

Tags: java, xpages

I'm working with the `org.openntf.domino` API in a personal XPage project and I'm running into an issue which I don't seem to get resolved myself. I have the following code:

```
public class SeasonService implements Serializable {

private Vector<?> seasons = new Vector();

public Vector<Season> getSeasons(){
    System.out.println("Retrieve all season entries");
    Database db = DominoUtil.getCurrentDatabase();

    View vw = db.getView(".AllDocuments");
    ViewEntryCollection coll = vw.getAllEntriesByKey("Season");

    Iterator<ViewEntry> it = coll.iterator();
    Vector<Season> l = new Vector();
    while(it.hasNext()){
        ViewEntry entry = it.next();
        l.add(fromEntry(entry));
    }

    return l;
}

private static final Season fromEntry(ViewEntry entry){
    ViewEntryEx vex = new ViewEntryEx(entry);
    System.out.println("Retrieve season from entry");

    //try {
        Season s = new Season();
        s.setDescription("Test");
        s.setKey("0000");
        //s.setDescription((String) vex.getColumnValue("Description"));
        //s.setKey((String) vex.getColumnValue("Key"));
        return s;
    //} catch (ColumnNameNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    //  e.printStackTrace();
    //}
    //return null;
    }
}
```

The domino Util class looks like this:

```
public static final Database getCurrentDatabase(){
    Session s = Factory.fromLotus(ExtLibUtil.getCurrentSession(), org.openntf.domino.Session.class, null);
    return s.getCurrentDatabase();
}
```

For some reason as soon as I try to initiate the View object the code returns with an Stackoverflow error. Anyone has a clue on what would be the cause?

Answer (score 0):

What milestone are you using? And would it be possible for you to share the app in question?

A stack overflow is usually indicative of an infinite regression, but I don't see anything in the .getView code that would seem likely to cause this. There was a point at which the null check on the resulting view wasn't there and it would throw an NPE, but I think that was resolved before the current release on OpenNTF.

```
    public View getView(final String name) {
    try {
        View result = Factory.fromLotus(getDelegate().getView(name), View.class, this);
        if (result != null) {
            result.setAutoUpdate(false);
        }
        return result;
    } catch (NotesException e) {
        DominoUtils.handleException(e);
        return null;

    }
}
```

Comment: Currently I'm using the 2.5mc version. I will provide a download link asap. The funny thing is that I used another milestone a few weeks back and didn't get such an error. (but because I reinstalled my system I lost that project .....)

Comment: I notice your view name is ".AllDocuments" Is the dot part of a personal standard or something?

I'm just checking that it's not a typo. If the Stackoverflow only occurred in the event of a null result, that would tell us more.

Comment: The dot Part is indeed a personal standard. It is derived from IT Factory. When I use the standard Java API's to retrieve the data there is no problem at all. Another strange thing is that the first time the application starts there is no error at all. The second time, a refresh for instance, it starts to occure. You can find the source here: http://www.jeroensomhorst.eu/REPHocke.nsf

Comment: I will run some local tests later tonight (Eastern Time). Thanks for reporting!